# Working with pr. lap times in php (h:mm:ss.000)

Tags: php, time

i'm quering a webapi and is returned lap times in this format. I'd like to to addition etc on this laptimes to get total time, average etc.
But i cant seem to spot the function i need to parse this format.

0:00:20.128
0:00:40.128
0:00:28.128

Any idea how to to this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly easy to parse manually. To convert this to an amount of time in milliseconds, which is probably what you'd want to do, just do this:

```
function lap_time_to_millis($lap) {
    $components = explode('.', $lap);
    $time_components = explode(':', $components[0]);
    return intval($components[1])
         + intval($time_components[2]) * 1000
         + intval($time_components[1]) * 60000
         + intval($time_components[0]) * 3600000;
}
```

Then, to convert milliseconds to a lap format, use this:

```
function millis_to_lap_time($millis) {
    $hrs = intval($millis / 3600000);
    $mins = str_pad(intval($millis / 60000) % 60, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $secs = str_pad(intval($millis / 1000) % 60, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $milli = str_pad($millis % 1000, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    return "$hrs:$mins:$secs.$milli";
}
```

Comment: that was amazingly fast, thanks! seems to work perfect